# How do you find how much disk space is left in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, hard-drive

I suppose I'd like to be able to find out for any storage, not just the system disk, but that's most important.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`-[NSFileManager attributesOfFileSystemForPath:error:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1411896-attributesoffilesystemforpath)

Comment: -[NSFileManager attributesOfFileSystemForPath:error:] doesn't return a dict with the key NSFileSystemFreeSize in it.

Comment: Whoops, you were right. Looks like I tried that on the class, not the instance.

Comment: Hi, what if one of the sub-folders in the path points to another filesystem, does the NSFileManager knows to ignore it when retrieving the attributes ?

Answer (score 13):

I use this:

```
NSDictionary* fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:@"/"
                                                                                   error:&error];
unsigned long long freeSpace = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] longLongValue];
NSLog(@"free disk space: %dGB", (int)(freeSpace / 1073741824));
```

Comment: My 2 cents - 1) use a NSString containing the path to a volume in place of @"/" to view information for other volumes. 2) it'd be better if we use unsignedLongLongValue instead of longLongValue.

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT**
fileSystemAttributesAtPath: is deprecated, use attributesOfFileSystemForPath:error: as NSD suggested. I made a mistake when I thought it didn't work.

```
// this works
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *attr = [NSFM attributesOfFileSystemForPath:@"/" error:&error];
if (!error) {
    double bytesFree = [[attr objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] doubleValue];
}
```

---

I tried this, attributesOfItemAtPath:error but the dict returned didn't seem to have the NSFileSystemFreeNodes key.

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *attr = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:@"/" error:&error];
if (!error) {
    NSLog(@"Attr: %@", attr);
}

2009-10-28 17:21:11.936 MyApp[33149:a0b] Attr: {
    NSFileCreationDate = "2009-08-28 15:37:03 -0400";
    NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 80;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = admin;
    NSFileModificationDate = "2009-10-28 15:22:15 -0400";
    NSFileOwnerAccountID = 0;
    NSFileOwnerAccountName = root;
    NSFilePosixPermissions = 1021;
    NSFileReferenceCount = 40;
    NSFileSize = 1428;
    NSFileSystemFileNumber = 2;
    NSFileSystemNumber = 234881026;
    NSFileType = NSFileTypeDirectory;
}
```

After [looking around a bit](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSFileSystemFreeSize), it seems like fileSystemAttributesAtPath: is the method that returns it. Weird.

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary *attr = [fm fileSystemAttributesAtPath:@"/"]; 
NSLog(@"Attr: %@", attr);


2009-10-28 17:24:07.993 MyApp[33283:a0b] Attr: {
    NSFileSystemFreeNodes = 5027061;
    NSFileSystemFreeSize = 20590841856;
    NSFileSystemNodes = 69697534;
    NSFileSystemNumber = 234881026;
    NSFileSystemSize = 285481107456;
}
```

Comment: “… use attributesOfFileSystemForPath:error: instead.” That's what NSD suggested, and you told him it didn't work. Does it work now?

Comment: Yeah, it does. Looks like I made a mistake before.

Comment: Two critiques: `error:` parameters take a pointer to a pointer to an object, `NSError **`. Thus, the correct null pointer constant is not `nil` (which would be a pointer to an object, either `<class-name> *` or `id`), it's `NULL`. More importantly, don't suppress the error return—pass a pointer to a variable there, and report the error if (and only if) the attempt to retrieve attributes fails. Silent failure is bad.

Comment: You're right on both counts. Added better handling to example code to be more instructive.

Comment: `fileSystemAttributesAtPath` is deprecated as of now.

Answer (score 2):

Hard disk device manufacturers, use:

1GB = 1000MB

1MB = 1000 KB 
etc.

If you see a 8GB USB stick in Windows always shows less space than real (like 7,8 GB) because it is considered 1 GB = 1024 MB). In OSX the same USB stick is 8GB (real).

so `(freeSpace / 1073741824)` must be `(freeSpace / 1000000000)`

at least in OSX

Comment: To who have downvote, I invite to look at the greek vocabulary for the meaning of giga, mega etc ..

Comment: Your answer is good & potentially useful trivia, but it doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm really fine with this (ie if my comment is OT), but unfortunately the answers here were simply mistaken if you consider the cocoa tag + harddrive. My answer implicitly contains a correction to the already posted code  (that should be ok since is not an improvement but a correction). So if you whant find the correct space left, you have to use multiple of 1000 instead of 1024 otherwise the result will be incorrect, also because cocoa already use that.

Answer (score 1):

Through swift you can get free space by using this function

```
func getFreeSpace() -> CGFloat {
      do {
         let fileAttributes = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfFileSystemForPath("/")
         if let size = fileAttributes[NSFileSystemFreeSize] as? CGFloat {
            return size
         }
      } catch { }
      return 0
   }
```

Comment: Do not post multiple answers with the same content. You already posted this here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36654477/1743880. Post one good answer and flag the other as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Get from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712527/how-to-detect-total-available-free-disk-space-on-the-iphone-ipad-device):

```
- (uint64_t)freeDiskspace
{
    uint64_t totalSpace = 0;
    uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0;

    __autoreleasing NSError *error = nil;  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];  

    if (dictionary) {  
        NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];  
        NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
        totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes unsignedLongLongValue];
        NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
    } else {  
        NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %d", [error domain], [error code]);  
    }  

    return totalFreeSpace;
}
```

The main difference is that you should use NSSearchPathForDirectioriesInDomains, otherwise I was getting correct value on simulator, but on the device '/' folder reference returns me something like 190MB which was not right.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0-4.0 on MacOS

I've done this for macOS and haven't had an issue.  The output is in bytes so you have to divide it by the 1024.

```
func getHD() -> String {
    do {
        let du = try FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: "/")
        if let size = du[FileAttributeKey.systemFreeSize] as? Int64 {
            return (String(size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) + "GB")
        }
        debugPrint(du)
    }
    catch {
        debugPrint(error)
        return "Check Failed"
    }
    return "Checking..."
}
```

The `FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: "/")` is just getting the various attributes available for the root directory's file system.  One of those attributes happens to be the Free Disk Space.

```
du[FileAttributeKey.systemFreeSize] as? Int64
```

You access that key (key:value) and typecast it to an Int to get your free disk space.