# Detect when the free space on disk change

Tags: objective-c, macos, filesystems, disk

I need to monitor the available free space on the disk using objective-c, especially when it changes.
If this is not feasible then I am interested to detect when the trash is emptied by the user.

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Comment: See the duplicate question [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626139/how-do-you-find-how-much-disk-space-is-left-in-cocoa

Comment: Not a duplicate. Question is not about knowing free space but being notified when it changes

Answer (score 0):

There are about a zillion things at any given moment that might be writing to disk; VM, console logs, programs, caches, preferences, the user, etc...

... thus, receiving a notice of whenever free disk changes is pretty much useless because you would be receiving such a notice all the time.

Watching for the trash being emptied shouldn't be too hard;  a kqueue could do it easily enough.  But that isn't likely to tell you much, either;  the trash might have 400MB in it or it might have 4K.

What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I am "just" trying to have something like in the bottom bar of the Finder, showing current free space. I am not interested by something super accurate, but just giving an idea.

Comment: Have a look at kqueues or dispatch sources, then. You might have to resort to periodic polling, but that is to be avoided.