# How to get Size and free space of a directory in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I want to access the actual size of  a directory, and also free space available in a directory.
I already used [NSFileManager defaultManager]attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error] method.
This method works fine for files but for directory, it does not provide actual value. Please help to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Directories don't have "free space"; the free space is a property of the filesystem in which the directory exists.  I think you want `stat(2)` and/or `statfs(2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the size of a directory using this particular method, the fastest, using Carbon, instead of NSEnumerator :
[here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/136498-obtain-directory-size.html#136503)

To calculate free space, you could use that method. Make sure you enter the full path of the volume :

`NSDictionary* fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileSystemAttributesAtPath:folder];`

`unsigned long long size = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] longLongValue];`

Where size is what you're looking for.

Comment: It should only be noted that (unfortunately) most Carbon functions are marked as deprecated. For example, `FSGetCatalogInfoBulk()` which is used in the code that you linked to, is deprecated as of OS X 10.8. It will probably still work, but should keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: unsigned long long size = [[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize] longLongValue];  i checked this method for root but its not give right value.

Comment: @MartinR you're absolutely right, thank you for bringing that.
Surjeet, have you entered the right path ? Because it's working for me.

Comment: @ceache Yes i have entered right path, i got every information about directory except size

Answer (score 2):

Through swift you can get free space by using this function

```
func getFreeSpace() -> CGFloat {
      do {
         let fileAttributes = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfFileSystemForPath("/")
         if let size = fileAttributes[NSFileSystemFreeSize] as? CGFloat {
            return size
         }
      } catch { }
      return 0
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>

-(unsigned long long)getFolderSize : (NSString *)folderPath;
{
    char *dir = (char *)[folderPath fileSystemRepresentation];
    DIR *cd;

    struct dirent *dirinfo;
    int lastchar;
    struct stat linfo;
    static unsigned long long totalSize = 0;

    cd = opendir(dir);

    if (!cd) {
        return 0;
    }

    while ((dirinfo = readdir(cd)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(dirinfo->d_name, ".") && strcmp(dirinfo->d_name, "..")) {
            char *d_name;


            d_name = (char*)malloc(strlen(dir)+strlen(dirinfo->d_name)+2);

            if (!d_name) {
                //out of memory
                closedir(cd);
                exit(1);
            }

            strcpy(d_name, dir);
            lastchar = strlen(dir) - 1;
            if (lastchar >= 0 && dir[lastchar] != '/')
                strcat(d_name, "/");
            strcat(d_name, dirinfo->d_name);

            if (lstat(d_name, &linfo) == -1) {
                free(d_name);
                continue;
            }
            if (S_ISDIR(linfo.st_mode)) {
                if (!S_ISLNK(linfo.st_mode))
                    [self getFolderSize:[NSString stringWithCString:d_name encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                free(d_name);
            } else {
                if (S_ISREG(linfo.st_mode)) {
                    totalSize+=linfo.st_size;
                } else {
                    free(d_name);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    closedir(cd);

    return totalSize;

}
```

You can also use `du` command.

> du -- display disk usage statistics