# How to get storage capacity of mac programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, storage

How do I get the total capacity, available space and free space in Cocoa?

As shown in the screenshot, I want to get this programmatically in my Cocoa application for macOS.

[image]

Comment: statfs(2) for C-based solution. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/statfs.2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my answer from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626139/how-do-you-find-how-much-disk-space-is-left-in-cocoa).

So I am posting what I did using that reference.

```
    NSError *error;

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDictionary *attr = [fm attributesOfFileSystemForPath:@"/"
                                                     error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Attr: %@", attr);
    float totalsizeGb = [[attr objectForKey:NSFileSystemSize]floatValue] / 1000000000;
    NSLog(@" size in GB %.2f",totalsizeGb);

    float freesizeGb = [[attr objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize]floatValue] / 1000000000;
    NSLog(@" size in GB %.2f",freesizeGb);
```

Hope that helps anyone else also.

Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

Use `-[NSFileManager mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:options:]` to get `NSURL`s for the volumes. For the `propertyKeys`, use `@[ NSURLVolumeTotalCapacityKey, NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityKey ]`. You probably want to use `NSVolumeEnumerationSkipHiddenVolumes` in the options.

Then, for each URL, call `-[NSURL resourceValuesForKeys:error:]` with the same property keys. This will give you a dictionary whose keys are `NSURLVolumeTotalCapacityKey` and `NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityKey` and whose values are `NSNumber` objects holding the corresponding quantities, measured in bytes.

If you need to format those values for display, use `NSByteCountFormatter`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please show me via code for getting a total capacity of mac as I am slightly new to mac development. Thanks...

Comment: This is my partial solution to use NSURL and NSByteCountFormatter:  

`NSDictionary *resources = [url resourceValuesForKeys: keys error: &error];

NSLog(@"NSURL resources: %@", resources);

if ([url getResourceValue: &availableSpace forKey: NSURLVolumeAvailableCapacityKey error: &error] == YES) {
 NSString *formattedAvailableSpace = [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount: [availableSpace longLongValue] countStyle: NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile];
 NSLog(@"availableSpace: %@ formattedAvailableSpace: %@", availableSpace, formattedAvailableSpace);
}
`